# Content Editor Web part missing office 365 - enabled Custom script

Tags: office-365, content-editor-web-part

I have enabled the custom script in office 365, but still i cannot view the content editor part in my site collection (Publishing).

However after enabling the custom script, the newly created site collection contains the content editor web part but the previous site collection still doesn't got it.

The help says that it takes 24 hours before the feature gets enable, its almost 48 hours now.

Answer (score 1):

Try to reenable Site Feature - Publishing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the term set owner before enabling the custom order, and the current owner can only change the setting of the term set.

Answer (score 0):

In 2022, you might have to enable custom scripting also at the site level via powershell.